# Can I combine Divination spells with Arcane Eye?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, vision-and-light

Can I use spells like See Invisibility or True Seeing to enhance my use of Arcane Eye?

If yes, do I need to cast those spells on the eye or myself?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Neat idea, but you can't.

[*Arcane Eye*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/arcane-eye) is not a creature, but simply a magical effect - and it is the one doing the seeing:

> You mentally receive visual information from the eye, which has normal vision and darkvision out to 30 feet.

It is only the eye that is viewing and sending you information - you are not actively using your own senses.

Because of this, neither *True Seeing* nor *See Invisibility* nor any other divination type will help you as they require the target to be a creature or object- and the *Arcane Eye* is neither.

### *[Scry](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/scrying)* would work!

This spell specifically states:

> You can see and hear through the sensor as if you were there.

If you had either *True Seeing* or *See Invisibility* going, then you'd be able to utilize those spells to boost your senses.

Answer (score 7):

## All relevant divination spells can't be cast on the eye

*Arcane eye* creates a spell effect as part of its effect which takes the shape of an eye:

> You create an invisible, magical eye within range that hovers in the air for the duration.

Notably, this eye is not a creature nor is it an object. This means that any spell that specifically requires a creature or object to target will not affect the eye. Unfortunately, that is the vast majority of spells (disregarding AOEs). *True seeing* is an example of such a spell. Since it targets creatures, it will not affect the eye.

Specifically though, *see invisibility* cannot be cast on the eye since it has a range of self, which means only the caster can be affected by it.

All relevant sight-affecting spells that I can find cannot be cast on the eye for these reasons.

## Spells that affect your sight do not affect what you can see out of the eye

The magical eye has its own ability to see and sense and that is outlined in the spell description:

> You mentally receive visual information **from the eye**, which has normal vision and darkvision out to 30 feet.

All the information comes from the eye specifically. Thus, nothing that affects your own vision will affect the information coming from the eye.

Contrast this with a spell like *scrying* which says:

> You can see and hear through the sensor as if you were there.

Thus, *scrying* lets you use any sight enhancements you have, but not *arcane eye*.